# Find the maximum of the length of 2 arrays

Tags: java, math, max, maxlength

I am passing 2 arrays to the controller with different lengths, I want to execute a for loop and length of that will be the max of the length of 2 arrays. 
I am not getting how to execute that. I tried Math.max but its giving me error as cannot assign a value to the final variable length.

```
String[] x =0;
x.length = Math.max(y.length,z.length);
for(int i=0; i < x.length; i++)
```

The no of elements in x and y are not fixed. it changes what we are passing from the front end.

Comment: X.length is a constant you can't change it.

Comment: Looks to be some question over your intent. Are you trying to create a new String array? Or are you only interested in using the Max length as a loop condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize the new array with the desired length:

```
String[] x = new String[Math.max(y.length,z.length)];
```

In case you don't need to create an array, just use the result of `Math.max` as conditional to stop your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(y.length,z.length); i++) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi Luiggi, you and I were mistaken. Based on code alone, it looks like OP is trying to create a new array, and loop over that. But after re-reading the question, it looks like they only care about using the biggest array length as a loop stop condition

Comment: @Trobbins well, still you have to initialize the array somehow, and this looks like the best way to do it based on the current description of the problem.

Comment: We were assuming OP is looping over a new array, though there is no context to imply that. Looks like OP saw so many `array.length` conditions in for loops that they tried to adapt that (with error).

Comment: @Trobbins I don't think so, but still I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I've done the same. Looking at the other answers, seems like there is ambiguity. In any case, @downvoter should change their vote, with your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just bring your `Math.max()` operation into the array's initialization.

```
String[] x = new String[Math.max(y.length, z.length)];
```

Here's an expansion for clarity:

```
int xLength = Math.max(y.length, z.length);
String[] x = new String[xLength];
```

---

Edit: Unless, OP, you're not interested in creating another array...

> I want to execute a for loop and length of that will be the max of the length of 2 arrays

Just bring your `Math.max()` operation into your `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < Math.max(y.length, z.length); i++){
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int max_length = Math.max(y.length,z.length);

for(int i=0; i < max_length ; i++){
 //...
}
```

you can use that `max_length` to create a new `String[]` if you are trying to create an array with total length of `y and z arrays`, like

```
String[] newArray = new String[max_length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to the maximum length of the arrays, create a new array with that length and then loop until that point.

```
int maxLen = Math.max(y.length, x.length);
String[] array = new String[maxLen];
for(int i = 0; i < maxLen; i++){
    // Loop code here
}
```